# How to pass data on the main Vue instance to components used by vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using vue-router all in one HTML file, no single file components. I am loading a component for a route, but how do I pass what's in the Vue data object to the component?

If I load the component without Vue-router it all works. But if I make the route load the component it won't work.

```
const searchResults = Vue.component('search-results', {
                props: [
                    'results',
                    'page',
                    'totalPages',
                    'resultsContainerHeight'
                ],
                template: 
                <div>
                    <div style="height: 30px;"></div>
                    <div id="results-container" v-bind:style="{ minHeight: resultsContainerHeight + 'px' }">
                        <div class="card border-dark mb-3" v-for="result in results">
                            <div class="card-body text-dark">
                                <span class="float-right">{{Number(result.distance).toFixed(1)}} kms</span>
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{result.name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav v-if="totalPages > 1">
                        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                            <li class="page-item" v-bind:class="{disabled: page == 1}">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="$emit('change-page',page-1)">Previous</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" v-bind:class="{active: index+1 == page}" v-for="(pageNo,index) in totalPages"><a class="page-link" @click="$emit('change-page',index+1)" href="#">{{index + 1}}</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item" v-bind:class="{disabled: page == totalPages}">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="$emit('change-page',page+1)">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            });
        const router = new VueRouter({
            routes: [{
                path: "/",
                component: searchResults,
                props: {
                    results,
                    page,
                    totalPages,
                    resultsContainerHeight
                }
            }

            ]
        });
        var app = new Vue({
            router,
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                results: [],
                latLng: '',
                page: 1,
                totalPages: '',
                resultsContainerHeight: ''
            }
```

Now I am getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: results is not defined

But I want the route to work the same was as if I load the component without the router.

Comment: I would advise you to move data from the `app` variable to the `searchResults` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component now is a child component of your main instance and cannot access the parents properties directly. However, there are several ways to do that.

For your simple use case it is fine to access the parent via `this.$parent` or just `$parent` in a template.

For more complex apps this approach quickly become impossible to maintain and you should take a look at `vuex`.